# Remove white space between div blocks

Tags: html, css

How can I remove these white space blocks around my div blocks?
My code is the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordionitem horizontal"></div>
    <div class="accordionitem vertical"></div>
    <div class="accordionitem vertical"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.accordion {
    width: 100%;
}
.accordionitem {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
       padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.vertical {
    width: 10%;
    height: 100px;
}
.horizontal {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/PqkGh/2/

Comment: Thank you all, I've got my solution now :) Need just a few minutes to mark it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: Font size works, you could also use line-height `.accordion { line-height:0em; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also remove the `display: inline-block` from the CSS and add `float: left`:

```
.accordion: after {
    clear: both;
}

.accordionitem {
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PqkGh/5/).

Comment: I do not know why this was down-voted, it seems to be a fine way to do this.

Comment: I like this one the most, just because I want to add a list inside the big div and that's working just fine with this solution.

Comment: I don't think using float for the layout is necessary, or beneficial in any way, in this case.

Answer (score 4):

use:

```
 .accordion {font-size:0px; }
```

This is happening because display:inline-block; makes the DIV's behave
like inline elements (like space between words)

Comment: Well that was easy... Thanks!

Comment: This is more or less a hack even though I thought this is the correct way to go

Comment: sure.. just remember to give font-size to any inner element with text in it ;)

Comment: @Huangism using 'display:inline-block' is becoming a pretty popular solution for this type of stuff.. you can say it's a hack but I think this should be the natural behavior of 'inline-block' and might end up in the specs.. who knows.

Comment: @webkit It's behaving the way it should be, the space is due to just that the space between each of the inline blocks. Just like when you have a space between spans. While this solution is handy but it forces you to give the children a proper font size.

Comment: @Huangism I know why there's a space, I'm saying I can't think of a case where I would change a 'block' element into 'inline-block' and still require the 'inline' spacing... Maybe it should remain when changing 'inline' elements to 'inline-block'.. or 'block' elements to 'inline'.. but that's just my opinion

Comment: @webkit I believe this is more about semantics than changing elements from inline or block to inline-block

Comment: This isn't a hack, but it's borderline. As long as you don't accidentally apply it to any unintended elements, it should do exactly what is intended.

Comment: @AlexW I agree. when I recall the hacks we used in the past for the likes of IE666, this one seems 100% semantically correct to me ;]

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the space between the divs

http://jsfiddle.net/PqkGh/3/

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordionitem horizontal"></div><div class="accordionitem vertical"></div><div class="accordionitem vertical"></div>
</div>
```

for better readability you can do

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordionitem horizontal">
    </div><div class="accordionitem vertical">
    </div><div class="accordionitem vertical">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I like the css the most, so I can just keep my HTML formating

Comment: @lordkain this isn't a workaround. It's the proper way to get rid of the space. The space is there because there is a space in the html

Answer (score 3):

**Inline-block** tends to add these spaces because it picks up on spaces/text between tags (including new lines). To remove these white paces, comment out the area between the DIVs like so

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordionitem horizontal"></div><!--
    --><div class="accordionitem vertical"></div><!--
    --><div class="accordionitem vertical"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with several ways

```
1. .accordion {font-size:0px; }

2.  .accordionitem{margin-right: -4px;}

3.  <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordionitem horizontal"></div><!--
        --><div class="accordionitem vertical"></div><!--
        --><div class="accordionitem vertical"></div>
    </div>
```

[reference link](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: @DhavalPanchal I don't agree with 1 or 2, as 3 is the proper way, but they all work

Comment: @DhavalPanchal I would have to disagree with Chris Coyier in this case. Option number two is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Several contributors have used “proper” or “correct” to define their approach. Would anyone care to describe the technical basis for their naming their approach as proper or correct.